# How do I correctly display xml structure with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, jupyter, export-to-csv

I'm looking for some insights on how to properly display this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <PRODUCT>
        <SUPPLIER>015</SUPPLIER>
        <PRODUCT_DETAILS>
            <KEYWORD>Paper</KEYWORD>
            <PRODUCT_TYPE>major</PRODUCT_TYPE>
        </PRODUCT_DETAILS>
        <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
            <REFERENCE>Class01</REFERENCE>
            <FEATURE>
                <FNAME>Colour</FNAME>
                <FVALUE>white</FVALUE>
            </FEATURE>
        </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
    </PRODUCT>
</HEADER>
```

For a simpler structure, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <PRODUCT_DETAILS>
        <KEYWORD>Paper</KEYWORD>
        <PRODUCT_TYPE>major</PRODUCT_TYPE>
    </PRODUCT_DETAILS>
    <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
        <FEATURE>
            <FNAME>Colour</FNAME>
            <FVALUE>white</FVALUE>
        </FEATURE>
    </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
</HEADER>
```

I've written a few lines that look like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(root), 2):

    details = [(child.tag, child.text) for child in root[i + 0]]
    features = [(child[0].text, child[1].text) for child in root[i + 1]]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[i[1] for i in details + features]], columns=[i[0] for i in details + features])

    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])

df

# df.to_csv("file_export.csv", index=False)
```

... and produce this output:

```
    KEYWORD PRODUCT_TYPE    Colour
0   Paper   major           white
```

What edits do I need to make, to output this:

```
    SUPPLIER    KEYWORD PRODUCT_TYPE    REFERENCE   Colour
0   015         Paper   major           Class01     white
```

Thank you for your help!

**Best,
~C**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will do the job

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HEADER>
    <PRODUCT>
        <SUPPLIER>015</SUPPLIER>
        <PRODUCT_DETAILS>
            <KEYWORD>Paper</KEYWORD>
            <PRODUCT_TYPE>major</PRODUCT_TYPE>
        </PRODUCT_DETAILS>
        <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
            <REFERENCE>Class01</REFERENCE>
            <FEATURE>
                <FNAME>Colour</FNAME>
                <FVALUE>white</FVALUE>
            </FEATURE>
        </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
    </PRODUCT>
</HEADER>'''

elements = ['SUPPLIER','KEYWORD','PRODUCT_TYPE','REFERENCE','FNAME','FVALUE']
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {e:root.find(f'.//{e}').text for e in elements}
data[data['FNAME']] = data['FVALUE']
del data['FVALUE']
del data['FNAME']

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print(df)
```

output

```
  SUPPLIER KEYWORD PRODUCT_TYPE REFERENCE Colour
0      015   Paper        major   Class01  white
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This completely solved the question I was asking, but not my problem. That's on me. I'm very new so excuse me.
How would I edit your code when my original document had multiple child nodes to <PRODUCT_DETAILS> with the same tag e.g., <KEYWORD> but different text. Your code only outputs one. I also have multiple of these: <FEATURE><FNAME>xyz</FNAME><FVALUE>zyx</FVALUE></FEATURE>. Lastly, I have more than one product. How do I output all the rows for them and not just one? (:

Comment: @Charles My answer solved the issue as you raised it. Please accept it. If you have other questions - create new posts.